# How to convert PHP iterable pseudotype to Iterator instance?

Tags: php, foreach, iterator, iterable

I have a PHP function that takes an `iterable` and I need to convert that to an `Iterator` instance.

The following expression works for me, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way:

```
$iterator = is_array($collection)
    ? new ArrayIterator($collection)
    : ($collection instanceof IteratorAggregate
        ? $collection->getIterator()
        : $collection);
```

The context, and reason I can't use foreach is that my function is a generator that returns a closure and I need to iterate within the closure.

Here is the code in context:

```
public static function chunkGenerator(iterable $collection, callable $chunkPredicate) {
    $iterator = is_array($collection)
        ? new ArrayIterator($collection)
        : ($collection instanceof IteratorAggregate
            ? $collection->getIterator()
            : $collection);
    assert($iterator instanceof Iterator);
    while ($iterator->valid()) {
        yield function () use ($iterator, $chunkPredicate) {
            do {
                yield $previous = $iterator->current();
                $iterator->next();
            } while ($iterator->valid() && $chunkPredicate($previous, $iterator->current(), $iterator->key()));
        };
    } }
```

Comment: I edited the title to ask a technical question rather than ask for an opinion.

Comment: Objects are also iterable.  I haven't handled that case.